# Urlencode with cURL in bash with newlines

Tags: bash, curl, newline

I am trying to send a request to our SMS gateway, where I want to put in some newlines in the SMS being sent.

So far, I got to this:

```
/usr/local/bin/curl -G --data-urlencode "text=*****centreon Notification *****\n\nType:$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$\nDate/Time: $DATE$" "http://192.168.11.248:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=user&password=password&from=12345678&to=87654321"
```

However, that doesn't work, as I get all the `\n`'s in my SMS, where there should be a new line.

I have a PHP script where the `\n` works, but as I cannot call a PHP script, I have to do this with a oneliner, where cURL comes into play.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can embed newlines in a quoted string in Bash, trivially.

```
/usr/local/bin/curl -G --data-urlencode "text=*****centreon Notification *****

Type:$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$
Host: $HOSTNAME$
State: $HOSTSTATE$
Address: $HOSTADDRESS$
Info: $HOSTOUTPUT$
Date/Time: $DATE$" "http://192.168.11.248:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=userpassword=password&from=12345678&to=87654321"
```

What are the trailing dollar signs supposed to accomplish?

If you prefer, Bash has a syntax for escapes in strings, like `$'Hello\nworld'`.  Notice the dollar sign before the opening quote.

Comment: The trailing dollar signs are how Nagios/Centreon handles the parameters to be passed to the command. Embedding newlines in bash worked perfectly - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can stick newlines into arguments using `$''`-style quoting with its escape sequences, or other quote types with literal newlines. I would better organize this though. That is one *very* long "one-liner".

```
declare -a a=(
    $'text=*****centreon Notification *****\n'
    "Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE"
    "Host: $HOSTNAME"
    "State: $HOSTSTATE"
    "Address: $HOSTADDRESS"
    "Info: $HOSTOUTPUT"
    "Date/Time: $DATE"
)

url=http://192.168.11.248:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=user&password=password&from=12345678&to=87654321

/usr/local/bin/curl -G --data-urlencode "$(printf '%s$\n' "${a[@]}")" "$url"
```

As an aside, ksh now supports URL encoding natively via `printf '%(url)q' '...data...'`, in which case curl may not be needed at all.

Comment: Hmm, your script looks fine, although I cannot use such a long one (with multiple operants), as it has to go into a nagios configuration file.

Comment: @FrederikNielsen Ah, well either is fine. This would be more for use as part of a larger Bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Nagios does not accept multiline value in command_line parameter, so you can do following:

```
/usr/local/bin/curl "http://192.168.11.248:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=userpassword=password&from=12345678&to=87654321&text=%2A%2A%2A%2A%2Acentreon%20Notification%20%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%0A%0AType:%20$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$%0AHost:%20$HOSTNAME$%0AState:%20$HOSTSTATE$%0AAddress:%20$HOSTADDRESS$%0AInfo:%20$HOSTOUTPUT$%0ADate/Time:%20$DATE$"
```

Comment: Actually it is not a good solution, because in this way the nagios macros (variabbles between $$) will not be URLencoded.

Comment: I've put a wrapper script here http://zszsit.blogspot.com/2014/03/send-sms-from-nagiosicinga-through.html
It works well with nagios/icinga and kannel